# Mix results params and search fields in solspace user

Tags: solspace-user

Is it possible to search in solspace user from search fields and hardcoded fields as attributes in the results tag?

Like so:

```
{exp:user:results group_id="6" 
                            search:js_makecvpublic="YES"}
                        <div class="search-candidate-result">
                            <h3 style="padding:0;">{js_makecvpublic} - {js_firstname} {js_lastname}, {js_addresscity}</h3>
                        </div>
                        {/exp:user:results}
```

I have a form which searches through various member fields and works ok. But I need to filter only candidates that have allowed their CV to be made publicly available and i dont want to have it as a hidden field in the search form as it can be easily changed.

When i add the js_makecvpublic to my search form as a hidden field, it works, when i hardcode it into the results tag, it doesnt. Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that is currently not available. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

In the meantime, although totals, and perhaps pagination, wouldn't be accurate (PHP could be used to get a total though), you could use a simple conditional inside `{exp:user:results}` to filter out users that have `js_makecvpublic` set to "YES". Eg:

```
{if js_makecvpublic == "YES"} ... {/if}
```